# Invoke a method when another method ends in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm making a tictactoe game where you can play against another person or an AI.  Two AI can also play against each other.  When two AI play against each other I got a stackover flow, guard page error.

What has happening, was when the AI would click on a button my "ClickHandler" method would be called.  At the end of this method I would calla method (playATurn) for the other player to pick a button and "ClickHandler" would be called again and I would have an endless recursion.

I have fixed this issue using a timer at the end of the method which calls "playATurn" after 1ms but this is slow.

My question is there an event or something else I can program that would call "playATurn" after my program has finished with "ClickHandler."

Thanks!

```
private void ClickHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button tempButton = (Button)sender;

    if (tempButton.Text != "")  // if is it empty
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button already has value!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return;
    }

    if (_isX)   // put the character in the Text property
    {
        tempButton.Text = "X";
        turn.Text = "O";
    }
    else
    {
        tempButton.Text = "O";
        turn.Text = "X";
    }
    _isX = !_isX;   // prepare for next character

    this._isGameOver = CheckAndProcessWinner();
    if (_isGameOver) gamesRemaining.Text = (--PlayerMenu.counterForNumberOfGames).ToString();
    if (_isGameOver && PlayerMenu.counterForNumberOfGames == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(playerOne.name + " Wins: " + playerOne.numberOfWins + " Loses: " + playerOne.numberOfLoses + " Ties: " + playerOne.numberOfTies);
    }
    else if (_isGameOver && PlayerMenu.counterForNumberOfGames > 0)
    {
        InitTicTacToe();
    }
    else if (!_isGameOver && PlayerMenu.counterForNumberOfGames > 0)
    {
        if (_isX)
            playerOne.pickMove(_buttonArray, playerTwo);
        else
            playerTwo.pickMove(_buttonArray, playerOne);
    }
    myTimer.Start();
}

private void playATurn(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isGameOver && PlayerMenu.counterForNumberOfGames > 0)
    {
        if (_isX)
            playerOne.pickMove(_buttonArray, playerTwo);
        else
            playerTwo.pickMove(_buttonArray, playerOne);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean. You can put playATurn(sender, e) at the end of method ClickHandler().

Comment: If I do that I get endless recursion and a stackoverflow.  Since my playATurn calls ClickHandler().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to run it *too* tightly, or the windows message loop want run and it won't update. Perhaps consider:

```
private void PerformMove() {
    // ... Your existing code
    if(runAgain) {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{
            PerformMove();
        });
    }
}
private void ClickHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    PerformMove();
}
```

This then goes via the message-loop per iteration, so the UI should be responsive... Just about.

Comment: CLickHandler // my existing code            [code]this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                playATurn(sender, e);
            });[/code]